# Calculate the domain of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( z^n+\frac{1}{2^nz^n} \right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Question.** Calculate the domain of convergence of
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( z^n+\frac{1}{2^nz^n} \right)$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm totally lost :C

I did this, but I don't know if is the correct procedure.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{z^{n+1} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}z^{n+1}}}{z^n+\frac{1}{2^nz^n}}$$

Comment: There is a problem with ratio test, as the terms are complex numbers. Perhaps first determine when single series $\sum z^n$ and $\sum (2z)^{-n}$ are convergent and then show that the original series is convergent iff each single series is convergent. Single series are sums of geometric progressions, so you actually do note need any test for determining the domains of their convergence.

Comment: Note that the series is the sum of two geometric series $A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$ and $B = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2z)^n}$. This shows that the convergence of both $A$ and $B$ is a sufficient condition for the convergence of the series in the OP. It is also not hard to show that this is a necessary condition. (Of course, this "converse" is not true in general, so you will need some argument justifying this.)

Answer (score 1):

If $|z| \ge 1 $ the $|z^{n}+\frac  1{2^{n} z^{n}}|\geq 1-\frac 1 {2^{n}}\to 1$ so then series is divergent. If $|z|<1$ then $\sum z^{n}$ is convergent so the given series can converge only if $\sum \frac  1{2^{n} z^{n}}$ is convergent. But this is true iff $|z| >\frac 1 2$ so the given series converges precisely when $\frac  1 2 <|z|<1$.